# SVG: public doctype collides with additional namespaces

Tags: svg, thymeleaf, doctype

I got a (probably trivial) problem with my SVG document:
Eclipse warned me that my document doesn't use Doctypes, so I searched [W3C's site for their doctypes](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) and chose the full DTD:
`<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">`
The problem is that I'm additionally using Thymeleaf to modify my documents, so I have declared my th-namespace (and some more) within the root:

```
<svg
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    ...
>
```

Of course, now eclipse moans about the fact, that my Thymeleaf attributes aren't defined for common svg-elements.
Now my question is what's best practice here?
Should I leave the doctype open? `<!DOCTYPE svg>`
I also [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) that SVG 1.2 doesn't need a DOCTYPE, at all.
All suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this helpful [article](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring/) about DON'Ts when working with SVGs.
It states that DOCTYPE declarations may cause problems. That's also the reason why SVG 1.2 omitted a doctype in the first place.
It's advisable to notate your used version and baseProfile as attributes within the root-element.
If your IDE keeps moaning, try to set the xml-standalone to "yes"; if that's not of any use, declare an empty doctype as you suggested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg>
<svg
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    //..
>
```

Comment: awesome, that actually solves all my questions! And thanks for that article, that is a nice reference for me; so now I'm gonna rework my SVGs, i guess :D